# Spring roo- gvNIX loupe addon not currently available

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-roo, gvnix, gvnix-es

when y run the setup show this message

```
roo-gvNIX> web mvc setup
Command 'web mvc setup' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)
roo-gvNIX>
```

my version of gvNIX is 1.5.1.RC4

any idea for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `web mvc setup` command is only available if some project has been created before and only if the `web mvc setup` command has not been executed before.

Create a project, configure the `jpa` persistence, create your entities and after that, tries to exeucute the `web mvc setup`. After that, you'll be able to install `jQuery`, `loupe-field`, etc.

Also, check the gvNIX  1.5.1.RC4 reference guide for more information about availability of the commands:

http://www.gvnix.org//assets/doc/gvnix-1.5.1.RC4-reference-docs.pdf

Hope it helps,